# Google cloud Big query UDF limitations

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, user-defined-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

I am facing a problem in Google bigquery. I have some complex computation need to do and save the result in Bigquery. So we are doing that complex computation in Java and saving result in google bigquery with the help of Google cloud dataflow.

But this complex calculation is taking around 28 min  to complete in java. Customer requirement is to do within 20 sec.

So we switch to Google bigquery UDF option. One option is Bigquery legacy UDF. Bigquery legacy UDF have limitation that it is processing row one by one so we phased out this option. As we need multiple rows to process the results.

Second option is Scalar UDF. Big query scalar UDF are only can be called from WEB UI or command line and can not be trigger from java client.

If any one have any idea the please provide the direction on the problem how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scalar UDFs with standard SQL from any client API, as long as the `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION` statements are passed in the `query` attribute of the request. For example,

```
QueryRequest queryRequest =
    QueryRequest
        .newBuilder(
            "CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetWord() AS ('fire');\n"
                + "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT corpus) as works_with_fire\n"
                + "FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`\n"
                + "WHERE word = GetWord();")
        // Use standard SQL syntax for queries.
        // See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/
        .setUseLegacySql(false)
        .build();
QueryResponse response = bigquery.query(queryRequest);
```

Comment: Hi Elliot, I have around 100 line JS code for this UDF. Should I write the the UDF in same way?

Comment: That's right. It should just go with the rest of the query text. Alternatively, you can load the contents of the JavaScript file [from GCS as a library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-external-libraries).

Answer (score 1):

> Big query scalar UDF are only can be called from WEB UI or command
>   line and can not be trigger from java client.

This is not accurate. Standard SQL supports scalar UDFs through `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION` statement which can be used from any application and any client - it is simply part of the SQL query:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions

To learn how to enable Standard SQL, see this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql
Particularly, simplest thing would be to add `#standardSql` tag at the beginning of SQL query.

Comment: On the link page it is written that "UDFs are temporary. This means you can only use them for the current query or command-line session. You do not use the UDF Editor tab in the web UI when creating a user-defined function for use with standard SQL queries. The UDF Editor tab is for use with legacy SQL."

Comment: Could you please let me know how to trigger Standard SQL supports scalar UDFs  from java client.

Comment: I extended answer to point out how to enable Standard SQL. The CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION clause will need to be prepended to every query which uses it.