# Google Cloud Dataflow Javascript UDF error when parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have used the Pub/Sub to BigQuery [template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java) to stream JSON data that are sent to a Pub/Sub topic. Through Dataflow I want to flatten the data to match the BigQuery schema and stream them.

Here is the Javascript UDF for the Dataflow process:

```
function transform(inJson) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(inJson);
    // variable declarations
    // ... 
    data['domain'] = obj['data']['domain']; // line 18
    ...

    return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

I've also tried:

```
data.domain = obj.data.domain;
```

I've just copied the example from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates#adding-fields) and extended it to flatten the JSON data.

Here is the error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "domain" from undefined in <eval> at line number 18
```

and the stacktrace:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "domain" from undefined in <eval> at line number 18
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:392)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeFunction(NashornScriptEngine.java:190)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.JavascriptTextTransformer$JavascriptRuntime.invoke(JavascriptTextTransformer.java:156)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.JavascriptTextTransformer$FailsafeJavascriptUdf$1.processElement(JavascriptTextTransformer.java:315)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.JavascriptTextTransformer$FailsafeJavascriptUdf$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:325)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:272)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:621)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:609)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery$PubsubMessageToFailsafeElementFn.processElement(PubSubToBigQuery.java:412)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery$PubsubMessageToFailsafeElementFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:325)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:272)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:621)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:71)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:122)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:325)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1233)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:144)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:972)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: <eval>:18 TypeError: Cannot read property "domain" from undefined
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:213)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:185)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:172)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Undefined.get(Undefined.java:157)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$1$7667A$\^eval\_.transform(<eval>:18)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:639)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.callMember(ScriptObjectMirror.java:199)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:386)
    ... 42 more
```

When I try the Javascript locally by passing some sample data it works as expected without any errors.

**UPDATE**

Turns out that Pub/Sub sends the data wrapped in " so I had to remove them from the start of the string and in the end. Also every " inside the JSON was escaped with \ therefore I had to remove them also in order to continue without any errors.

Comment: See if this post answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/43050926/1031958

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Pub/Sub sends the data wrapped in `"` so I had to remove them from the start of the string and in the end. Also every `"` inside the JSON was escaped with `\` therefore I had to remove them also in order to continue without any errors.

Comment: Can you share the code on how you removed the enclosing "" , i tried a bunch of stuff but i always hit an error

Comment: @pavneettiwana sorry for the late reply, I've just seen your comment. Here is the code in case you haven't found a solution and for future visitors. `var fixJson = inJson.split(/,{2,}/).join('').split(',{').join('{'); var data = JSON.parse(fixJson);` This should be used at the start of the function that I have posted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's an error in your JavaScript code.

```
data['domain'] = obj['data']['domain']; // line 18
```

Throws the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "domain" from undefined in <eval> at line number 18
```

If the variable isn't being reinitialzed somewhere, you could try to put the JSON in a **single line** when publishing to Pub/Sub
i.e.

```
{"name":"Sam","age":21}
```

Comment: Turns out that Pub/Sub sends the data wrapped in `"` so I had to remove them from the start of the string and in the end. Also every `"` inside the JSON was escaped with `\\` therefore I had to remove them also in order to continue without any errors. Thanks for your comment!